# When using HGroup in Flex, trying to get last element to fill remaining width

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I have an HGroup that has 7 child Groups in it. Each of the first 6 child Groups has width/height set to specific values. I'd like the 7th element to fill the remaining width of the HGroup so I've given it a value of 100%. This works but only when the app starts up. After the HGroup in question has it's width initially set, it won't resize. If I listen for the ResizeEvent from it and trace out the width, when it goes larger  than the original width, it will trace the width out and it does go up (though the content doesn't resize), but when I resize to below the original width, the ResizeEvent stop firing.

Every parent of the HGroup has it's width set to 100% too. None are explicitly set to a number. I feel like I have other components that do this.

I have "hacked" it by taking the last element out of the group and then setting it's right, top, bottom, and binding its left side to the last element in the HGroup's x plus width properties. This works... but I feel like I shouldn't have to do it that way.

```
<WindowedApplication>
    <Group width="100%">
        <Group width="100%">
            <Group width="100%">
                <Group width="200" />
                <VGroup width="100%">
                    <Group width="100%">
                        <HGroup width="100%">
                            <Button width="60" />
                            <Button width="60" />
                            <Button width="60" />
                            <Button width="60" />
                            <Button width="60" />
                            <ButtonWithProblem width="100%" />
                        </HGroup>
                    </Group>
                    <Group width="100%" />
                </VGroup>
                <VGroup width="270" />
            </Group>
        </Group>
    </Group>
</WindowedApplication>
```

The problem is with ButtonWithProblem, it's width gets set when the app loads and whatever it's width is set to at that point seems to be it's new minimum width and if i resize teh screen smaller it just starts croppring rather than shrinking. If I resize the app larger, then it also won't stretch to fill the HGroup size.

So I've hacked it by taking ButtonWithProblem out of the HGroup and have it as a sibling to HGroup and set it's top, right and bottom to 5 and then binding the left property to the width of the HGroup (which works, just seems hackish)

Comment: Can you please post some code to show how your groups are setup? When do you set the width of the last group 'initially'?

Comment: The only hardcoded width/height I have for this HGroup and any of it's ancestors is at the WindowedApplication level. There the width/height for the entire app is set to 1024/768. Everything down to that HGroup is set to width 100% (for direct ancestors, there are siblings at some points that have hard-coded values, but those should affect this). But the 1024/768 isn't calculated into this anyway as during boostrap I maximize the screen. I'll work on adding some pseudo code to show my parenting

Comment: Edited the original question with some code showing the parenting

Comment: Just tried your code in a simple AIR app and it seemed to work absolutely fine. I could see the last button expand and contract. Could be something else going on with your code. Is this a AIR project?

Comment: It is an AIR project yes. It's possible that it's something else in the code as it's a huge codebase. So unfortunately if that simple example worked then it'd be hard for me to provide even a minimal version of what is included in this particular project unfortunately :/